# Stripe: Tiered pricing for one time purchase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am working on a project where I need to capture one time payments from an account. For a bit of background: The account has many users, where users are part of teams as team_members. I have another model we can call projects where teams are affixed to the project. It is on these individual projects that I would like to have a checkout button. The price for this one time payment should be calculated based on the number of individuals in a team, that are part of this project.

My issue is that I am not 100% sure how to achieve this for one time payments in stripe. Should I set this up alike that if I were to sell an individual item? Product (with name, description and price) and an Order to affix to the user?

I've built subscriptions plans in Stripe before, but have never really used one time payments. Any guidance on setup here would be really great.

**Small Edit:**
When a project is created, a team is selected. That team size is known to the project.

If I have 3 tiers for pricing:

1-5 people in a team is $x

6-20 people in a team is $y

21+ people in a team is $z

How would I go about invoking the correct tier based on the team size for the project?

If you want to keep users on your application while paying, following the [web payment example](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#ruby) is what you'll want to do. You would provide the amount when [creating the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent).

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time

Comment: Tiered pricing is for recurring subscriptions and won't align with the pricing you're trying to model. See my answer below for one time payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the amount you want to charge in your own business logic. Once you've got that number, there are several ways you can collect one-time payments with Stripe.

If you want to offer the most flexibility for supported payment methods with the lowest amount of integration effort, [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time) would be a great option. You would supply the amount and a description with the line items while [creating the checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#create-checkout-session).

If you want to keep users on your application while paying, following the [web payment example](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#ruby) is what you'll want to do. You would provide the amount when [creating the PaymentIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent).

Comment: Nolan. Thank you for your thoughts with this. I’ll calculate server side and send to stripe. In subscriptions plans reside in stripe. Makes things much simpler in controlling and sending the amount to stripe